# Some updating commands could not be generated automatically the database returned the following error unexpected error

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to add a connection to MySql server however when trying I am getting an error "Some updating commands could not be generated automatically the database returned the following error unexpected error" I have checked all privileges for the user that I am using and have reinstalled all MySQL connectors etc and still nothing. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[[MySQL Data Source Wizard not working on Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069886/mysql-data-source-wizard-not-working-on-visual-studio-2017/52196380#52196380][Look])

You can try changing your Connector/NET to version 6.9.8, and changing the MySQL for Visual Studio as well to version 1.2.7

If it prompts"Failed to add relation(s) Specified cast is not valid".
Don't worry, you can normal builb project, dataGridView will load data normally.